# TinyMCE editor - allow Angular template tag

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-5

I've been trying to get TinyMCE to [allow a template](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#exampleusingextended_valid_elements) tag for use in my angular app.

ie. `<aside #tagname></aside>`

Adding this to the config still strips out any `#...`.
`extended_valid_elements : 'aside[#]'`

Adding all reformats it to an attribute with `=""`.
`extended_valid_elements : 'aside[*]'`

Is there a way to do this?

UPDATE:
[github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular/issues/220](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular/issues/220)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the parser is removing attributes that start with '#' even if they're in the `extended_valid_elements`.

For example if you set `extended_valid_elements : 'aside[#test]'` you can confirm that it did add that attribute by running `tinymce.activeEditor.schema.elements.aside` and confirming that the attribute is there.

However it looks like the [SAXParser](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/develop/modules/tinymce/src/core/main/ts/api/html/SaxParser.ts#L374) does not support characters other than the ones that match the regex pattern \w - the code is hard to follow though so I wouldn't be surprised if I was wrong.